# c# работа с sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Здравствуете! Я работаю в c# с база данных sqlite, успешно подключается но когда делаю запрос дает такой ошибка SQL logic error no such table

Comment: Видимо, вы делаете запрос к таблице, которой нет? Напишите текст запроса и приложите диаграмму БД.

Comment: Здравствуете нет таблица ест в базе наверно это какое то ошибка

Comment: Покажите как делаете запрос

Comment: Здравствуете Спасибо за внимание вот

Comment: sqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Global.sqliteConnection);
sqliteCommand.CommandText = "select * from test";
sqliteReader = sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Почему вы решили, что таблица есть в бд? Как ваша строка соединения выглядит?

Comment: sqliteConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\cities.db;Version=3");
                sqliteConnection.Open();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой таблицы нет, возможно, ошибка в имени таблицы или вообще в запросе, а может, таблицу еще не создали.